# Show $\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}h \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(nh)=\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, improper-integrals

Let $f$ be a monotonous function over $[0, \infty)$ for which the improper integral $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges. I want to show
$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}h \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(nh)=\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
First, we notice that for the integral to converge $f$ has to be decreasing. Now we have
$$\int_{(n-1)h}^{nh}f(x)dx\geq f(nh)h\geq\int_{nh}^{(n+1)h}f(x)dx$$
Summing from $n=1$, we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{(n-1)h}^{nh}f(x)dx\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(nh)h\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{nh}^{(n+1)h}f(x)dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx\geq h\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(nh)\geq \int_{h}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
We apply the limit
$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx\geq \lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}h\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(nh)\geq \lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}\int_{h}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx\geq \lim\limits_{h\to 0^+} h\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(nh)\geq \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
Finally
$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+} h\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(nh)= \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
Is this line of reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Well, $f$ need not be decreasing, but you can always replace $f$ by $-f$, so we may assume without loss of generality that $f$ is decreasing. Other than that, your argument is excellent.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to go over my proof!

Comment: I have a related question. Will the same result hold true for $f(x)=x^ae^{-x}$ where $a>0$? (Note that $f(x)$ is decreasing only on $(x_0,\infty)$ for some $x_0$, not entirely on $(0,\infty)$)?